# Understanding equation in linear regression

Tags: regression

The following paragraph is taken from p24 of the book *The Elements of Statistical Learning, 2nd.Ed* by Hastie, Tibshirani & Friedman, where $X$ and $Y$ are random vectors, and bold $X$ is the $N \times p$ matrix of data:
[image]

In other words, it is claimed that $$x_0^T (\hat\beta-\beta)=X(X^TX)^{-1}x_0\varepsilon$$

Why is that true? The book's phrasing suggests that it is simple to see it, but
it seems that the only similar derivation in the book prior to this is the fact that $\hat\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ is the least squares solution to $Y=X^T\beta$.

Comment: Please make sure that my edit is consistent with your intention. I was trying to make it concordant with the pasted part of the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

$$x_0^T(\hat{\beta} - \beta) = x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\varepsilon$$

and it follows from

$$\begin{align}x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\varepsilon &= x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}X^T(Y - X\beta)\\[2ex] &= x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY - x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}X^TX\beta\\[2ex] &= x_0^T\hat{\beta} - x_0^T\beta\\[2ex] &= x_0^T(\hat{\beta} - \beta)\end{align}$$

You might have been mislead (as I was for a minute) by the equation, which states the relationship between r.v. $X$ and $Y$. But linear model equation is (note $X$ instead of $X^T$)

$$Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$$

if you take $X$ as $N\  \times  p$ matrix and where $\varepsilon \sim N(0, I_n\sigma^2)$

Comment: +1 Hope you don't mind my trying to keep notational consistency with the OP (pasted fragment). If it doesn't reflect your intention, just roll it back.